# Filter collection by multiple attributes of its elements - QueryDSL

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I am working on a dynamic filter component based on QueryDSL with the use of SpringData for query execution. Thus I create `Predicate` instances from the received data ad pass it to `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`. For dynamic access to entity attributes I use generic `PathBuilder` typed to the entity class.

Consider the following (simplified) code:

```
class Offer {
    List<LanguageToName> names;
}
class LanguageToName {
    String name;
    String language;
}
```

When I try to query `Offer` entites, that have in their collection `name` element with attribute 'abc', I simply create the predicate as follows:

```
pathBuilder.getCollection("names", LanguageToName.class).any().getString("name")
    .like("%" + fieldData.getFieldValue() + "%");
```

However, I was unable to come up with a solution to filter the collection by multiple attributes of the containing objects with the use of `PathBuilder`. When I append the code above with `.and()` and access the collection again via the `pathBuilder` variable, I naturally get the result equivalent to appending sql query with `AND EXISTS...`, which is not the desired result. I also tried to use `getCollection().contains()`, but I was unable to create the `Expression<LanguageToName>` that would describe such case.

Is there a way to create a `Predicate` that would filter entities by multiple attributes of the elements from a collection, that is a field of the queried entity?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue and finally solved this with subquery (however, it seems to me that it works only for 1 level of nestedness).

My initial predicate was (it was making 2 independent sub-queries):

```
Predicate predicate = codeTable.customer.id.eq(customerId)
                .and(codeTable.qualifierResults.any().customerQualifier.type.eq("TARGET_TYPE"))
                .and(codeTable.qualifierResults.any().customerQualifier.referenceType.code.eq("TARGET_CODE"));
```

But the correct predicate that I ended up with was:

```
BooleanExpression customerQualifierCondition = JPAExpressions
        .selectFrom(codeTableQualifierResult)
        .where(codeTableQualifierResult.in(codeTable.qualifierResults),
                codeTableQualifierResult.customerQualifier.type.eq("TARGET_TYPE"),
                codeTableQualifierResult.customerQualifier.referenceType.code.eq("TARGET_CODE"))
        .exists();
Predicate predicate = codeTable.customer.id.eq(customerId).and(customerQualifierCondition);
```

The idea is to write 1 separate sub-query where you apply all necessary conditions at once (instead of applying them for your collection independently).

Comment: Hello there, small world :). Okay-ish solution; doesn't seem like there's anything better OOTB, unfortunately.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre hi, such coincident to see ex-coworker to comment on this answer :D

Comment: Small world indeed

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same problem in my project.
My workaround is to build the exists subquery manually.

Assuming that your both classes are mapped as Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Offer")
public class Offer {

    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "offer")
    List<LanguageToName> names;
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "dcsdba", name = "Language_To_Name")
public class LanguageToName {

    @Id
    String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Offer_id")
    private Offer offer;

    String name;
    String language;
}
```

A simple query with any():

```
BooleanExpression namesFilter = QOffer.offer.names.any().name.eq("Esperanto");
```

maps to

```
select
    offer0_.id as id1_7_ 
from
    offer offer0_ 
where
    exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            dcsdba.language_to_name names1_ 
        where
            offer0_.id=names1_.offer_id 
            and names1_.name=?
    )
```

A subquery:

```
BooleanExpression namesFilter = JPAExpressions.selectOne()
            .from(languageToName)
            .where(languageToName.offer.eq(QOffer.offer)
                    .and(languageToName.name.eq("Esperanto")))
            .exists();
```

Maps to:

```
select
    offer0_.id as id1_7_ 
from
    offer offer0_ 
where
    exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            dcsdba.language_to_name languageto1_ 
        where
            languageto1_.offer_id=offer0_.id 
            and languageto1_.name=?
    )
```

which matches perfectly previous SQL.
You can add additional conditions like:

```
BooleanExpression namesFilter = JPAExpressions.selectOne()
            .from(languageToName)
            .where(languageToName.offer.eq(QOffer.offer)
                    .and(languageToName.name.eq("Esperanto"))
                    .and(languageToName.language.like("E%")))
            .exists();
```

Comment: what is type of languageToName in .from()?

Comment: @user1955934 `QLanguageToName`

Comment: Lesiak how to use subquery in case of mongodb? jpaexpression is only for relational db?